# Find IP of website via Chrome console

Tags: google-chrome, dns

I have just changed the DNS records for a website, but they have yet to propagate on the East coast. Fortunately, I can see the change via my West coast proxy.

I need to get the IP of the new server that the new records are pointing to. Is there a fast and easy way to do this via the Chrome developer console?

Comment: Ans here: https://superuser.com/a/1254200/78897

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking through the console, I don't see any built-in function to do this. However, there are several Chromium extensions that do what you want.

One of them is [`ipvfoo`](http://code.google.com/p/ipvfoo/) ([web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ecanpcehffngcegjmadlcijfolapggal)). It displays the hostname and corresponding IPv4/IPv6 address for all requests made when loading the current page:

[image: ipvfoo screenshot]

Answer (score 127):

Actually yes you can.

1. Go to Developer Tools > Network.
2. Reload your page.
3. Select one of the URLs from the domain in question. The IP will be
   shown under Headers > General > Remote Address.

Comment: I get a different result when I use ping. I was testing on a parked domain, so may there was some kinda redirect that doesn't show up in browser history.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works if you actually get a page to look at.  If it doesn't serve a page there ("This site can't be reached" or similar) then there won't be any urls to inspect.

Comment: I stand corrected; there won't be any Headers to inspect.  It did load up after 30 seconds or so.  However there were only "Provisional" headers, which still didn't give the IP.

Comment: Weirdly, this doesn't work for example.org. The IP is 93.184.216.34 in the header, but when I go there, I get a 404 error.

Comment: @AaronR. This is most unfortunate when you are trying to troubleshoot why a DNS lookup is failing (e.g. to confirm that the local DNS server isn't giving you the LAN IP address and the fact that you are getting the external IP address is why the page load is timing out!)

Answer (score 13):

You can use this tab in Chrome, it shows you all the IP addresses that the browser is serving pages from.

Just type this into the browser URL and you should be good from there!
**chrome://net-internals/#dns**

Comment: This is no longer true in the latest versions of Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, I'm seriously upset that they removed this feature from Chrome with no replacement.. 
Also didn't hear many people talk about it's removal either. But it was a seriously useful tool! :(

Comment: Indeed, pretty unfortunate :(

Comment: ???  This still works

Comment: This still works in Chromium (115.0.5790.110) and Vivaldi (6.1.3035.257).

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't have to be through the Chrome console, just `ping` the website in command prompt and it will give you the IP address.

Comment: My windows command prompt isn't routing through my proxy the way my browser is =( It just gives me the IP of the old server if I do that

Answer (score -1):

If your problem is (was) that the IP address would flip back and forth between the old and new one, then one way to prevent the flip on your computer is to setup the IP address in your `/etc/hosts` file.

That file has a list of IP and corresponding names. For example:

```
8.8.8.8       example.com
```

I often do that when I switch my DNS IP addresses since I usually have the caches setup for at least 1h and often 1 day (My IPs change rarely).

You can do the exact same thing under MS-Windows. The main problem is to find the `/etc/hosts` file. It's actually buried within the `C:\Windows\system32\drivers` directory (that directory changed slightly between versions of Windows, I think, but it's there at least in Win8 and Win10). In newer versions of MS-Windows the file is read-only by default. May sure to make it read/write before trying to edit it.

For a browser to pick up the new address, you may have to restart it. Browsers may also have caches as pointed out by @BaldockJa's answer.