# How to get remote IP in Google Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

How do I get remote IP in Developer Tools Network tab? I can see the remote IP in Firefox using Firebug under Net. How can get this remote IP in Chrome?

If this is not possible in Chrome, is there extension available in Chrome to get this?

Answer (score 21):

Rightclick the table **header**. Find for ≪Remote Address≫. Click it.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

When you're in the Network tab of the Developer Tools menu, you can click on the Paths in the left-hand "Name" column. This will bring the Request Header, and should contain a field "Remote Address" which is the remote IP you're looking for.

Comment: I had this question and after a few brief searches found your answer. It is still exactly how you access the remote address (IP) in Chrome Dev Tools. I appreciate your insight.

Comment: Not anymore. They seem to have removed this method of getting the IP address.

Comment: @wp-overwatch.com I disagree. It is still there.

Comment: It's working for me again too.

Answer (score 5):

Nowdays they have a column that can be added on Network tab:

Right-click the column headers and select 'Remote Address' column.

Answer (score 0):

Though i couldn't find the exact solution for this. I can use the following chrome extension to get the remote ip.

Server IP: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/server-ip/lllhkijapbmlekoldcoohglpihmcjdgj

ShowIP: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/showip/agoljmemkbciolpigpabjfkagboolkcj